# What does ".UNTIL !ZERO?" mean in x86 asm?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
SENDS PROC NEAR
MOV CX,16
.REPEAT
   .REPEAT
      IN AL,CSTAT
      TEST AL,20H
   .UNTIL !ZERO?
   LODSB
   OUT DATA,AL
.UNTILCXZ

RET
```

This is a x86 asm program for the PC16550D to read 16 bytes. The outer loop repeat 16 times. CSTAT is checked to see whether the data is received.
   In ".UNTIL !ZERO?", does ZERO mean the zero flag?  What does "?" and "!" mean?

Comment: Those are not x86 instructions. This looks like some sort of macro assembler.

Comment: Looks like MASM, specifically.

Comment: The dot directives were added to MASM 6.11 (actually ML.EXE, any version after 6.00) back in the days of MSDOS 6.22 (maybe before). The sequence | .REPEAT | ... | .UNTIL !ZERO?| generates a jz to loop back to the code just after the .REPEAT. The loop exits when TEST AL,20H results in the zero flag being cleared (when AL bit 5 is set). One of the purposes of the dot directives is to reduce the number of local labels in source code.

Comment: @rcgldr Under your guide I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94b6khh4.aspx) .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a post test loop condition that matches when the zero flag is unset.

The [.UNTIL directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-until) ends a [.REPEAT block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-repeat) and has the syntax: `.UNTIL condition`

In the situation in question `!ZERO?` is the condition. This is an expression with 2 operators. The [! operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-logical-not-masm-run-time) is a logical negation. The [ZERO? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-zero-q) checks the status of the zero flag. Combined they check for the zero flag being unset.